# how to delete multiple records through checkbox in gridview using asp.net

Tags: c#

i want to delete multiple record through checkboxes in gridview in asp.net. i am using code "foreach loop" but there is something error.kindly guide me.
however " For loop" is working nice but i want to use foreach loop.

i used for loop in gridview for multiple delete record in asp.net but how to use foreach loop in gridview.

```
foreach (GridViewRow r in GridView1.Rows)
{
    CheckBox GvRcvCbItem = r.FindControl("cbMaster") as CheckBox;
    int index = r.RowIndex;

    if (GvRcvCbItem.Checked)
    {
        String abc = GridView1.Rows[r].Cells[1].Text;
        string MyDelQuery = "delete from Employee where ID= " + + "";
        dm.SetData(MyDelQuery);
    }

    for (int a = 0; a < GridView1.Rows.Count; a++)
    {
        CheckBox GvRcvCbItem = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[a].FindControl("cbMaster");
        if (GvRcvCbItem.Checked)
        {
            string MyDelQuery = "delete from Employee where ID= " + GridView1.Rows[a].Cells[1].Text + "";
            dm.SetData(MyDelQuery);
        }
    }
```

i want delete multiple rows like using for loop.

Comment: You have to remove items from a list going from end to beginning so you do not skip any items : for (int a = GridView1.Rows.Count - 1; a >= 0; a--)